# check if find command return something (in bash script)

Tags: linux, bash

i have the following bash script on my server:

```
today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
find /backups/www -type f -mtime -1|xargs tar uf /daily/backup-$today.tar
```

as you can see it creates backups of files modified/created in the last 24h. However if no files are found, it creates corrupted tar file. I would like to wrap it in if..fi statement so id doesn't create empty/corrupted tar files.

Can someone help me modify this script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One relatively simple trick would be this:

```
today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
touch /backups/www/.timestamp
find /backups/www -type f -mtime -1|xargs tar uf /daily/backup-$today.tar
```

That way you're guaranteed to always find at least one file (and it's minimal in size).

Answer (score 7):

You can check if result is ok then check if result is empty :

```
   today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
   results=`find /backups/www -type f -mtime -1`


    if [[ 0 == $? ]] ; then
     if [[ -z $results ]] ; then
      echo "No files found"
     else
      tar uf /daily/backup-$today.tar $results
     fi
    else
     echo "Search failed"
    fi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find /backups/www -type f -mtime -1 -exec tar uf /daily/backup-$today.tar {} +
```

Using `-exec` is preferable to `xargs`. There's no pipeline needed and it will handle file names with spaces, newlines, and other unusual characters without extra work. The `{}` at the end is a placeholder for the file names, and `+` marks the end of the `-exec` command (in case there were more arguments to `find`).

As a bonus it won't execute the command if no files are found.

Comment: hi, executing find /backups/www -type f -mtime -1 -exec tar uf /daily/backup-$today.tar {} +  gives error: find: option `-exec' requires an argument

Comment: @Kupe3 Are you sure you typed it exactly as written? That should definitely work...

Comment: Definitely the best answer. `+1`

Comment: Good answer from a functional standpoint. However, it could be important to note that this runs `tar` once for every file, and each time it runs, it has to open the output file, seek to the end, and append something, so it could have serious performance issues/implications for large data sets...

Comment: @twalberg You're thinking of `-exec cmd \;`. The `-exec cmd +` form with a plus instead of a semi-colon runs the command once with all file names appended.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Doh... missed that little difference. You're right with that, however, might the `+` form not run into issues with too many file names on the command line? Maybe that's just a shell limitation, though... Off to run a couple tests... Also, Kupe3's comment might be hinting at the possibility this is a GNU-ism that isn't available everywhere...

Comment: @twalberg It will build as long a command-line as it can, up to `ARG_MAX` characters. So it can still execute the command multiple times, but it will minimize the number of invocations. The `+` form is [POSIX standard syntax](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1/find/), not specific to GNU's version.

Comment: It doesn't work. Double checked. Maybe my OS doesn't include this command.

Answer (score 0):

`xargs -r` does nothing if there is no input.